# Custom Class not loading in Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, autoloader

I have a file called `InvoiceDataSource.php` and it's path is `app\Core\Forms\Invoice\InvoiceDataSource.php`, and that file contains this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Core\Forms\Invoice;

class InvoiceDataSource {

public function getAllCustomers(){

    return Customer::selectRaw('id as `value`,'.
                     'name as `label`')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
}

}

?>
```

I have included this in `composer.json` file as well like so,

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories",
        "app/Core/Forms/Invoice/InvoiceDataSource.php" 
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

It has also been added to autoloader in `autoload_classmap.php` file.

Now when I am trying to access this in the controller like this

```
//
public function getDataSource($id,Request $request){

    return InvoiceDataSource::getAllCustomers();

}
```

But for some reason the error read this,

```
{message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceDataSource' not found",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "/home/zrehan/projects/erp/app/Http/Controllers/FormController.php"
line: 88
message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceDataSource' not found"
trace: [{function: "getDataSource", class: "App\Http\Controllers\FormController", type: "->"},…]
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is triggered because your code is not using the right class, this is what it is looking for:

```
App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceDataSource
```

Which would simply be looking for the file `InvoiceDataSource.php` in your controller folder.

To change the class it is looking for use `use`.

This is because since you are in the controller namespace, when you name a class without the `use` attribute, it defaults to the controller (`App\Http\Controllers`) namespace.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// ...

use App\Core\Forms\Invoice\InvoiceDataSource;

// ...

class SomeController expands Controller {
  // ...

  public function getDataSource($id,Request $request){

      return InvoiceDataSource::getAllCustomers();

  }

// ...

}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comments you have different alternatives as well when including a class with a different namespace:

1) Use the entire class namespace

```
  public function getDataSource($id,Request $request){

      return App\Core\Forms\Invoice\InvoiceDataSource::getAllCustomers();

  }
```

2) Or if you have multiple classes with the same name under different namespaces you can use as:

```
use App\Core\Forms\Invoice\InvoiceDataSource as DataSource
use App\Core\Mailer\Invoice\InvoiceDataSource as DataSourceMailer
// ... etc
```

Comment: Is it possiblle to use something likereturn ```\App\Core\Forms\Invoice\InvoiceDataSource\InvoiceDataSource::getAllCustomers();``` because I may have multiple files in the future and I won't want to do this everytime .

Comment: @Rehan Yes, that's correct. You can use the entire namespace; and you can also `use as` (`use This\Namespace\Class as NamespacedClass`). Which would allow for you to use a custom name for that particular class.

Comment: That help. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rehan no problem... I didn't want to add it to the answer since I thought it would clutter it up too much... I will go ahead and add those up there.